# php array error - scalar value

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry guys, not being lazy, I know others have had the same error message solved but I still couldn't figure it out so I had to ask.

I have 2 2d arrays each with a string and a corresponding int.

I'm trying to compare the strings in the first array to the strings in the second and if they are the same, i want to add the corresponding integers together.

I am getting the error - "Cannot use a scalar value as an array" on the 7th line

```
for($countOne=0; $countOne<10; $countOne++)
    {
    for($countTwo=0; $countTwo<10; $countTwo++)
     {
       if($blekko_Array['url'][$countOne]==$bing_Array['url'][$countTwo])
       {
         $blekko_Array['score']['$countOne'] = $blekko_Array['score']['$countOne'] + $bing_Array['score']['$countTwo'];
        }
     }
    }
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
foreach ($blekko_Array as &$blekko) {
    foreach ($bing_Array as $bing) {
       if($blekko['url']==$bing['url']) {
           $blekko['score'] += $bing['score'];
       }
    }
}
```

For one thing, your code is hardwired to look through 10 items, so if your array has less than 10 entries, you'll get errors on the missing ones.

Comment: Thanks again andrew. It fixed the error but there's a new one in its place pointing to that last line of code.

Cannot use assign-op operators with overloaded objects nor string offsets

Comment: I've run the code without a problem; so there might be an issue with the data that you have - I think that might happen if one of the entries doesn't have a 'score' already.

Comment: Try switching out that line to: `$blekko['score'] = $blekko['score'] + $bing['score'];`

Comment: Thanks for your help andrew, when I get to the bottom of it I'll post back to let you know what I was doing wrong. Cheers

Comment: Andrew your code worked! It was an issue with the structure of my array. Thanks for all your help!